# What's the python file to startup multiple celery worker?

Tags: python, django, celery

When I am running the following code

```
python manage.py celery -A test worker -l info -Q test -n test.%h
```

It will kick off multiple python process to work as workers, I'd like to check the code how it kick off multiple process and how different process communicate with each other. But I check project of django, celery and django-celery, and don't know which file I should look at.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick breakdown of what happens when you run your code:

- `celery -A test`: defines the app (file) to be run, in this case, "test"
- `worker -l`: defines the log level, in this case "info"
- `-Q test`: name of the queue to listen to, in this case "test"
- `-n test`: name of the host.

If you wish to see how your app is defined, you should probably start at the test.py file, which should, according to your line command, contain all the settings for this particular Celery app